# ROS Navigation: Global and Local Planner

Tags: ros, navigation, stack, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way to modify the local planner so that the robot would always move within a certain distance of the Global Path. And in this case, if an obstacle appeared on the map and covered the global path, and re-planning required the robot to move outside this predefined distance of the original global path, the robot should just stop.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188264/ros-navigation:-global-and-local-planner/) by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 651 on 2014-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-29**:
Which local planner are you using?

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-07-29**:
I'm using ROS default local planner (DWA or Trajectory Rollout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With DWA, you can bias the robot toward staying on the global path by increasing the path_distance_bias parameter.

http://wiki.ros.org/dwa_local_planner#Trajectory_Scoring_Parameters

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-07-30**:
Thanks, but this is not exactly what I want to do. Your suggested way will force the robot to stop if an obstacle appears on the global path, but I want the robot to replan if there is a path within a certain distance of the global path, and stops otherwise

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-30**:
That kind of behavior requires more complex tuning of move_base, and the functionality for that is not yet available.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-07-30**:
Maybe I should open another thread for this question, but is it possible to manually update the costmap so everything outside the certain distance of the global path become obstacles, so that the robot never moves to those areas?